# How do I put this hyperlink (to a search result) in my svg-file?

Tags: javascript, php, svg

I have a hyperlink to a search-result:

```
http://www.example.com/search.php?page=1&search=A_0001#anchor
```

This works fine.

However, I need to put this hyperlink into a svg-file:

```
<a xlink:href="http://www.example.com/search.php?page=1&search=A_0001#anchor"><polygon points="000,000 000,000 000,000 000,000" id="A_0001" /></a>
```

This results (in the svg-file) in a **XML-parse error** pointing to the second equals sign.

These hyperlinks work fine, but will only show the search page:

```
<a xlink:href="http://www.example.com/search.php"><polygon points="000,000 000,000 000,000 000,000" id="A_0001" /></a>

<a xlink:href="http://www.example.com/search.php?page=1"><polygon points="000,000 000,000 000,000 000,000" id="A_0001" /></a>
```

This link works fine too, but only shows the search page with *A_0001* in the seach box:

```
<a xlink:href="http://www.example.com/search.php?search=A_0001#anchor"><polygon points="000,000 000,000 000,000 000,000" id="A_0001" /></a>
```

However, I need *page=1* AND *search=A_0001#anchor* for this to work... The search engine itself is a given; I can't change anything about that. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Any help would be much appreciated!
Robert

Comment: urlencode the ampersand: `http://www.example.com/search.php?page=1%26search=A_0001#anchor`

Comment: The XML-parse error pointed to the 2nd equals sign. So I urlencoded the 1st, the 2nd and both of the equals signs. That didn't work. But this does. Thank you! :)